# Text extraction with SpaCy python library Jupyter

Tags: spacy

I am using **Jupyter Notebook** for text mining and data Processing, after extracting my text from a pdf file i used **SpaCy library** to extract all the proper nouns processed but the problem is that sometimes it gives me the same name twice.
this is the pdf file that i'm using :
**https://drive.google.com/file/d/16LicTfEuQQRwVwTyt2bo1QfWS5vapC0c/view?usp=sharing**

============Code=====================

```
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern1 = [{'POS': 'PROPN'}, {'POS': 'PROPN'}] 
pattern2 = [{'POS': 'PROPN'}, {'POS': 'PROPN'},{'POS': 'PROPN'}]
matcher.add('FULL_NAME', [pattern1])
matcher.add('FULL_NAME', [pattern2])
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    print(doc[start:end])
```

===============**Output**=====================

**Sarra Ben**

**Sarra Ben Moussa**

**Ben Moussa**

**Ghofrane Challouf**

**Malika Ben**

**Malika Ben Slima**

**Ben Slima**

Comment: This gives you 3 times the names with a middle name because all 3 combinations match your patterns: 1st and middle name, middle and last name, all 3 names

Comment: How can i fix that?